# How to show on sg.Multiline the feedbacks from Model.fit on real time

Tags: python, command, pysimplegui

I have created a PySimpleGUI app, which perfoms the training of a keras model.

I have created a popup window which displays the terminal outputs...but only at the end of the training....
Question: how can I get the outputs on a real time or at least every 5 seconds??

````
##### TEMP COMMMAND PROMPT
def display_cmd(M2_model,XD,dyy,Epochs):
    Tr_Status=False
    layout = [
        [sg.Multiline(size=(110, 30), echo_stdout_stderr=True, reroute_stdout=True, autoscroll=True, background_color='black', text_color='white', key='-MLINE-')],
        [sg.Button('Start Training'),sg.Button('Exit')]]

    window = sg.Window('Realtime Shell Command Output', layout)
    while True:  # Event Loop
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit') or Tr_Status==True :
            break
        elif event == 'Start Training':
            M2_model.fit(XD,dyy,epochs=Epochs,validation_data=(XD,dyy))
    window.close()
    return M2_model
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to add threading to start your training, or it will be blocked in the GUI event loop when training.

```py
from numpy import loadtxt
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import threading


def training(window):
    # load the dataset
    dataset = loadtxt('pima-indians-diabetes.csv', delimiter=',')

    # split into input (X) and output (y) variables
    X = dataset[:,0:8]
    y = dataset[:,8]

    # define the keras model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_shape=(8,), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    # compile the keras model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    # fit the keras model on the dataset
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)

    # evaluate the keras model
    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y)
    print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
    window.write_event_value('Training Done', None)

layout = [
    [sg.Multiline(size=(110, 18), reroute_stdout=True, autoscroll=True,
        background_color='black', text_color='white', key='-MLINE-')],
    [sg.Button('Start Training'),sg.Button('Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('Realtime Shell Command Output', layout)

running = False
while True:  # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'Start Training' and not running:
        running = True
        threading.Thread(target=training, args=(window,), daemon=True).start()
    elif event == 'Training Done':
        running = False

window.close()
```

Comment: Hi Jason...Thanks a lot! With the above I can finally display on the Multiline the console info. Now the question is how do transfer the trained model to the main program, in my previous code it was the return M2_model.

Comment: I did it by returning from the def training. Thanks a lot for your eye opening solution.